# Draw line with markers in WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I am new in WPF Graphics and I can't find answer to my question.

I am trying to draw a line with point markers in WPF Canvas? Is someone have idea how to do it?

Best Regards

Comment: Yes, I have an idea. Go to MSDN like everybody else: [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Closed. See my answer in the duplicate question. It includes full source code and is based on standard recommended WPF patterns and practices such as DataBinding and DataTemplates.